# how to animate div from left and the next div will animate at top

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, jquery-animate

I am just new in the javascript.:) and I want to animate the first div from left and the next animation will be animate in top. How should i work on this;

myhtml:

```
<div id="small-img1">
        <div id="slideimg">
            <div><img src="images/resize_1346910724.jpg" /></div>
            <div><img src="images/resize_1347348425.gif" /></div>
            <div><img src="images/resize_1347354705.png" /></div>
            <div><img src="images/resize_1347403947.jpg"/></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

myjs script

```
setInterval(function() {
  $('#slideimg > div:first').animate({left:"-62px"},500).appendTo('#small-img1');
},  4000);
```

Comment: I can't quite tell what you're asking - please be more clear, your question is a bit random.

Comment: more details on what you want to achieve pls :)

Comment: Sorry guys. for example i have my first div animate from left, and the next showing of div, i want to change the animate({left:"-62px"},500) to animate({top:"-62px"},500). is it possible? thanks

Comment: how do you define next `showing of div`? is it second div with img/ the showing of the first div next time ie next page load